# How to remove slug from url (custom post type)

Tags: urls

how to remove slug from url ?

```
example.com/example/new-post/
```

how to remove `/example/`?

Comment: Where is example coming from? Is it a page, category or your root dir?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you `register_post_type()`, one of the args is `rewrite` where you can reset the URL to something else. Maybe you can play with this -- try leaving it blank?

Pro tip: You will have to reset permalinks after you do this.

Answer (score -1):

Admin Dashboard > Settings > Permalink: Choose Custom Structure then set your custom structure.

Comment: not works, i want to fully remove /example/ not change with something else

Comment: So that means your WordPress is installed in a folder named 'example', Right ?

Comment: delete htaccess file and save again custom structure settings.

Comment: adding details to your answers will help improve your score